# Android 12 Splash Screen Exit Animation adds extra space at the bottom of the screen below the BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-12, android-bottomnavigationview, android-splashscreen

When the exit animation of the Android 12 Splash Screen ends it adds some extra space below the BottomNavigationView as shown in the screenshots below

**While the Splash Screen's exit animation is running**
[image]

**When the Splash Screen's exit animation is over**

[image]

**activity_main_2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_navigation_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="prateek_gupta.physical_device_tester">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_logo_animation</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.PhysicalDeviceTester</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package prateek_gupta.physical_device_tester;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreenViewProvider;

import prateek_gupta.physical_device_tester.databinding.ActivityMain2Binding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMain2Binding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener(new SplashScreen.OnExitAnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSplashScreenExit(@NonNull SplashScreenViewProvider splashScreenViewProvider) {
                TranslateAnimation rightTranslateAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,-1f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0f);

                rightTranslateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                //rightTranslateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                rightTranslateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        splashScreenViewProvider.remove();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                splashScreenViewProvider.getView().startAnimation(rightTranslateAnimation);


            }
        });
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
}
}
```

So my question is how can I get rid of that extra space??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is there with the dependency, so in the **app/build.gradle** file change the dependency from

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha02'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
}
```